# KnockoutJS not applying beforeRemove and afterAdd on nested templates

Tags: knockout.js

I've been building a nested query editor in knockoutjs and added animations to it using the beforeRemove and afterAdd options on a template in foreach mode. It works just fine on the first level of nesting, but not when manipulating filters in a child filter group.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in KnockoutJS? Is afterAdd and beforeRemove not supported for nested templates? If so, is there a workaround?

Here is [my jsfiddle of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/daedalus28/98GwD/).

Also, is there a way to change the animation behaviour based on what is being added/removed? I'd like to have different animations for adding/removing filter groups then adding/removing filters themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into the issue described in this [post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/are-your-templates-working-overtime.html).  Basically, your inner template depends on $data.filters and ends up re-rendering the entire template whenever an item is added.  So, your animation is not happening, because the entire list is getting re-rendered from scratch each time.

Here is the sample with a small amount of re-factoring in the template to push the "if" logic into the template binding: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/UkGTF/

Also, if you start using [1.3beta](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/) with native templates, then you can use `if`, `with`, and `foreach` control-flow bindings to simplify this further.

Comment: Since this worked, you inspired me to revisit having separate animations for different components, and did so [successfully](http://jsfiddle.net/daedalus28/vpjhZ/), albeit a bit inelegant

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the second part of the question myself. For the benefit of anyone who may have landed here from google:

I switched the afterAdd and beforeRemove functions to be explicitly declared (and out of the markup), and then did some checks on the elem element with jQuery to figure out whether it's a filter or filter group, applying different animations appropriately.

Here is the [final fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daedalus28/vpjhZ/)